# Clickable text label inside an input

Tags: javascript, css, html

As this picture shows, any easy way to create a clickable label inside an input

[image]

Comment: Positioning and z-index.

Comment: @ceejayoz thats kinda hacky

Comment: How else are you expecting to be able to put a label inside an input?

Comment: @ceejayoz thats why i was asking. if theres a good way

Comment: Yes. Positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like that:

```
<input value="" placeholder="Password" style="padding-right: 60px;"><a href="#" style="margin-left: -60px; padding-left: 10px;">Forgot</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8bka73n/

Comment: And if you want a click on the text to focus the input, just surround the whole thing with a label: http://jsfiddle.net/t8bka73n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes my friend I did the same on my page. Here is the code for you

```
<input name="password" type="password" style="padding-left:5px;width:200px;height:30px; border-right:none;border-left:3px solid #000000;border-top:3px solid #000000;border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"><input name="sendpass" type="text" style="width:50px;height:30px;border-right:3px solid #000000;border-left:none;border-top:3px solid #000000;border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" value="Forgot?" onclick="location.href='pageurl.html';">
```

You can also take a look to a demo I created just for you

https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/8/

Comment: You can also add rounded corders and edit it as you need it to look like. Good luck